# How can I use the Windows (Super) key?

Tags: windows, keyboard

The Windows key seems to not have any use in Ubuntu, but since I'm just coming from Windows I'm used to this key having some function.
**How can I make good use of the Windows key in Ubuntu?**

I've seen that I can remap keys in System>Preferences>Keyboard>Layout>Options><kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd> key behavior, but I have no idea what the choices *meta, super, hyper* mean. The *help* button in this dialog doesn't give any specifics about them.

I've  experimented a little and found that *meta* seems to have some use, like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> = Me menu, or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is the shutdown menu, but for some keys (B, I) it's more like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (bold, italic). Haven't found any further.

What would a useful setting be for a Linux newbie?

Comment: I asked a seperate question about the other keys: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-do-meta-super-and-hyper-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a very simple way to add some useful key combinations in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486/not-so-well-known-features-of-ubuntu/2158#2158):

1. Go to `System` → `Preferences` → `Keyboard Shortcuts`.
2. Scroll through the list to find any action you want to assign to a keyboard shortcut.
   Example: `Home Folder`
3. Click in the right-hand column and then enter your desired key combo.

   Example: <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
4. Test your new combo.
5. Done!

*Note: I've realized after writing this answer that [dv3500ea wrote a similar answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19556/how-can-i-use-the-windows-key/19580#19580) which he claims doesn't work and added a part about compiz that I don't quite "get". But the simple approach works for me. I've upvoted his answer.*

Comment: What should I pressed for `Super+K`? As I am not seeing any "Super" word on my keyboard keys. Please suggest!

Comment: @RubyLovely: Linux people don't want to call it [the Windows key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key) but that's what it is. Note that some keyboards don't have that key, especially on laptops. Historically, there was another kind of keyboard that did have a "[Super key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_%28keyboard_button%29)".

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use it like in windows, to trigger the menu, go to System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts. Scroll down to and click on 'Show the panel's main menu'. Click on the right hand cell, which should change to 'New shortcut...' and press the Windows key.

**EDIT**: turns out this doesn't work but you can make it work by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then entering

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu --type string "Super_L"
```

You can bind it to other things as well. You can use it as part of a key combination in for another shortcut or for an action in compiz. For example, I have my Windows key bound to the *Initiate Window Resize* action (because this is easier than trying to grab the sides of the window) which can be found in [Compiz Config Settings Manager](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) under Window Management -> Resize Window.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Windows key tab is useful for compiz fusion toggling of windows.  It's also a great key to assign to your own custom shortcuts due to it's general lack of use in the linux world.

Comment: Wait, toggling of windows is Alt+Tab, and toggling of tabs is Ctrl+Tab. What kind of toggling do you mean?

Comment: with compiz-fusion there are different options for window switching...ring or whatever. in my specific case i use it for ring window switching.  you could use it for whatever

Answer (score 2):

I am using it as a keyboard layout switcher (to type in different language)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to people other than kubuntu, but I was having a hard time assigning just the press of the windows key.

Turned out that ctrl+f1 was mapped to the windows key, so having my activity panel ( i wanted the full screen launcher, not the regular launcher ) mapped to ctrl+f1 made the solo press of the windows key work.