# How to stop Mod4-P from switching the display?

Tags: gnome, compiz, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> very frequently to scroll backward in the command history, but I often mistype it as <kbd>Mod4</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>, which is bound to the switch display function.

I've searched around Keyboard shortcuts and CompizConfig, etc., but I couldn't find where <kbd>Mod4</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> is bound. What controls that?

Comment: I'm uncertain as to which key is Mod4 - is that the ["Super" key](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys)?

Comment: It's the "Win" key. or `Super_L` in the output of `xev`.

Comment: Read **[this](http://askubuntu.com/a/585204/209676)** question/answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable global <Super>-p shortcut?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68463/how-to-disable-global-super-p-shortcut)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disregard my other answer, it's incorrect.

There are laptops out there that have a physical button for video output switching [hardcoded to send Win+p](http://mjg59.livejournal.com/121851.html).  This is why [Ubuntu now interpets Win+p as a video output switching key](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/539477).

This is hardcoded in gnome-settings-daemon and [can be disabled in gconf](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/539477/comments/64) by setting

```
/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/xrandr/active
```

to `false`.  This workaround probably has a nasty side effect of breaking your real video switch key, if you have one.

P.S. This feature is added via an Ubuntu-specific `debian/45_support_new_video_key.patch`, but upstream gnome-settings daemon [will do the same thing](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=623223) in a different gnome-settings-daemon plugin (media-keys).  It is therefore likely that this gconf workaround will stop working in Natty.

P.P.S. There's an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/694910) claiming that stealing Win+p this way is not nice for people who have sane hardware and want to use it for something else.

Comment: Now I have convinced my self to learn not to press Win-p.

Comment: Switching from macOS to Linux on a daily basis this has been the bane of my existence, Win+P opens the source browser in VSCode on macOS, so glad there is a solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Ubuntu 14.04** simply:

`dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/active false`

At the command line :)

Comment: Please note that this also disables other media keys such as volume up, volume down, etc.

Comment: Simply follow **[this](http://askubuntu.com/a/585204/209676)** solution!

Answer (score 2):

Install `compizconfig-settings-manager`, run it, press `Advanced Search >`, enable the checkbox for searching in setting values, and do a search for `<Super>p` (and `<Mod4>p`, just in case -- both spellings appear to work).

On my machine I find that `<Super>p` is bound by two disabled plugins: ADD Helper and Shelf.

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately they are not found in CCSM. (I have tried to find `>p`, but only get `<Mod4>Print`. )

Comment: You're right -- if I plug in a second monitor, <Super>p does something entirely not what CCSM implies it should.

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of Ubuntu, dconf is used (instead of gconf) for changing the gnome-settings-daemon setting:  see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/68487/79981).

Answer (score 0):

## On Ubuntu **Quantal**

#### Find all bindings to <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>

```
gconftool-2 -R /apps | grep "<Super>p"
gconftool-2 -R /system | grep "<Super>p"
```

#### Unbind them

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/compiz-1/plugins/shelf/screen0/options/triggerscreen_key "" --type String
gconftool-2 -s /apps/compiz-1/plugins/addhelper/screen0/options/toggle_key "" --type String
```

Comment: doesn't help on ubuntu 15.10