# Where does the Mod4+P key binding come from?

Tags: keyboard, display, shortcut-keys

On my laptop (Toshiba Portege R705) the `Mod4+P` key combination toggles between different display modes: single monitor, mirror display, and extended display. I would like to disable this binding, because it can be annoying when pressed by accident. Moreover, there is already the `Fn+F5` hardware key with the same functionality, so the binding probably comes from software. Unfortunatelly, I cannot find anything related in the Keyboard Shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be related to the BIOS: see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/539477) and [here](http://mjg59.livejournal.com/121851.html).

[Marius](https://askubuntu.com/users/136/marius-gedminas) pointed this ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20113/how-to-stop-mod4-p-from-switching-the-display)):

> This is hardcoded in gnome-settings-daemon and can be disabled in
>   gconf by setting
>
> ```
> /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/xrandr/active
> ```
>
> to false. This workaround probably has a nasty side effect of breaking
>   your real video switch key, if you have one.

Comment: This might be somehow related with this particular laptop, I don't remember having this issue on other hardware.

Comment: Thanks for researching that. This is wrong on so many levels!

Comment: I'm glad to help ;-)