# How can I determine what command a given keybinding is invoking?

Tags: xorg, shortcut-keys

The key chord WinKey-p (hold down the right WinKey and press "p") causes my monitor configuration to cycle through some very strange and suboptimal settings.  It seems that whatever is causing this this is happening before my window manager is catches the event, because putting a window-manager binding on top of it does not change the behavior.  It actually happens with multiple window managers (sawfish and metacity) and multiple accounts (my regular and root.)

How can I figure out what command is being invoked when I press these keys?  It's not showing up when I run top, even when I run it with the minimum delay and mash WinKey-P repeatedly.

(This is actually on a linux mint 12 system.  Hope that's close enough, since this is basically a generic linux question.)

Comment: I have the answer to what is causing the problem in this case.  It is gnome.  But I am still interested in how to answer the general question.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/20113/how-to-stop-mod4-p-from-switching-the-display