# Unity Super + D shortcut doesn't work

Tags: unity

`Super key + D` shortcut doesn't work in show desktop functionality for me in Unity. I have searched and found solutions for adding a button in Unity launcher but I don't want that. I just want the keyboard shortcut to work for speed.

I found that `Ctrl + Alt + D` do something similar but `gedit` window doesn't bother to care for it.

Comment: That is odd, the keyboard shortcut works on my machine. I upgraded from 10.10. You should be able to find the appropriate action in keyboard shortcuts in the Control Center (my laptop is packed away atm, can't check).

Comment: I did a fresh install, and it doesn't work, other shortcuts work though

Comment: My Super-D gone too, hmm.. It was working yesterday. Updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went to `Power Button` > `System Settings (Control Panel)` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` and changed the shortcut key for the action "minimize all windows and set focus to desktop" to `Super + D` from `Ctrl + Alt + D` and now `gedit` obeys it too.

Its weird but its a bug that I certainly have no idea to reproduce. Another weird thing is I had to change it to `Super + D` & for some it works by default but since it seems to work fine now, I shall be marking this as the answer.

Comment: Some strange effect after that - Super-D mostly working, but first time Dash is displayed, it's a bug

Answer (score 15):

There already is a keyboard shortcut that lets you see the desktop. It is just mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. If you wish, you can remap it to <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Search for *Keyboard* settings. Open *Shortcuts* tab. Move to *Navigation*. Scroll down until you see the option *Hide all normal windows*. Double click on it and press <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Now, <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will show you the desktop from now on.

[image]

- [What are the meta, super, and hyper keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys)

Answer (score 7):

Just got to settings ---> appearance ---> behavior ---> add show desktop to the launcher

then try the keyboard shortcut again

Comment: woah!! is it documented anywhere?.

Comment: this worked. Wonder if it will keep working.

Answer (score 1):

For those without an "Appearance" option in their settings, try this. This is an easy way to show desktop in Ubuntu 18.04 L.T.S. without installing any third-party apps. It may work for other releases as well. Go to Settings->Devices->Keyboard then scroll to "Navigation Section." Click "Hide all normal windows" which is probably set to "disabled." Enter your new keyboard shortcut, which I set to CTRL+Alt+D. Voila! Instant desktop!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com)! The question is about the Unity desktop environment, however this answer applies only to Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

go to  **Preferences** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts** ->

1. Window Management
2. Sound
3. **Desktop** -> Here you can add a new shortcut for that
4. Accessibility

Comment: I will have to add a custom shortcut for it? Was it removed in Unity? And your instructions are for gnome, in Unity, we go to `Power Button > System Settings (Control Panel) > Keyboard settings`. And even if I am adding a custom shortcut, how would I associate it with the action?

Comment: You need keyboard shortcuts and on mine its mode4+D to show desktop

Comment: ah yes I meant Keyboard shortcuts only

Answer (score 0):

You have somehow saved another keybinding for that action. To go back to the default keybindings run this:

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/keybindings
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/metacity/global_keybindings
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/metacity/window_keybindings
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 i use  `Ctrl + Super + D`