# Cannot use Meta + D to show desktop

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity Super + D shortcut doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39118/unity-super-d-shortcut-doesnt-work)

I cannot use <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to show desktop on a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10. I have used both the alpha and beta versions and it didn't work in either of those. However, I was expecting it to work in the final release.

There is also no mention of any shortcut that shows the desktop.