# How do I get my taskbar back?

Tags: unity, taskbar

When I restarted my Ubuntu workstation after a firefox crash, my taskbar disappeared. I'm referring to the bar at the bottom of the screen, where the currently-open programs are displayed. Also, I remember I could switch from one virtual screen to the next one there. At the very right, there was a button on it that would minimize all windows and show the desktop.

What program do I need to start to get it back?
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Which task bar?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome panel .

Comment: do not know. how do i find out?

Answer (score 1):

Its Easy, hold `Super+Alt+click` on the upper task bar and click add new panel. Then using the same key combinations select `add to panel`  and then select the options you want such a workspace switcher, etc

Comment: and where do i get an overview over the running programs?

Comment: Its easy, hold <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+click... What is the "[super](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys)" key?

Comment: one of the options in the `add to panel` list should show running programs.

Comment: 'Super' is the Meta or Windows Key!

Answer (score 0):

I reached this in search of an answer and found a solution myself. Maybe it will help the others. In the meanwhile 16.04, there is a possible to do this using tweak-tools.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Go to Extensions and activate : `Display a window list at the bottom of the screen`. Please see the screenshot ( 3rd point from below )

[image]

Comment: I do not see "Extensions" anywhere in the gnome-tweak-tool or unity-tweak-tool.

Comment: @jpapple updated my answer with a screenshot. its strange that you dont see the extensions