# Accidentally removed default gnome panel applications

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-panel

I accidentally removed the default Gnome panel menu on the top right (containing clock, mail, volume and shutdown options). After, I tried to get the menu back by adding some apps but that did not solve the problem. I then stumbled upon a reset via the terminal, however, the menu remains missing and the apps I added are still there.

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/
killall gnome-panel
```

and

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

System: Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome classic.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I did this recently as well. Hold <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right Click to add to panel then search for 'Indicator applet complete'. Add that to the panel and everything should be back to normal. The <kbd>Super</kbd> is typically the one with  the Windows logo on it on most PCs (see [What are the meta, super, and hyper keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys)).

Answer (score 2):

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `Right-click` an empty area of your panel (in Gnome 3), and choose “`Add to Panel…`“, then scroll down till you find “`Menu Bar`”, then drag and drop it on desired place or click `Add`.