# separate meta and hyper keys in unity with XKB

Tags: unity, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I want to use `Caps Lock` for the `Hyper` key because I need it in Emacs, so in `/etc/default/keyboard` I use the relevant `XKBOPTIONS`.

However, Unity seems to react to both: even though it passes `Hyper_L` through so it works in Emacs, the launcher and/or the HUD keeps popping up. I thought this was happening because `xmodmap` shows that both of them are assigned to `mod3`, so I ran `xmodmap` with

```
clear Mod3
clear Mod4
add Mod3 = Hyper_L
add Mod4 = Super_L
```

which now works, but I am under the impression that `xmodmap` is deprecated. Is there a way I can achieve the same with `XKBOPTIONS`?

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that I am asking this because `xmodmap` settings are lost when I switch layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently do it with an option, however it is possible to change it without modifying any system files. See my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/794087/514921.  I believe this will persist across layout changes, but I have not tried it.