# Assign keyboard shortcut to Hyper in GNOME

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to assign keyboard shortcuts to key combinations with the Hyper key in GNOME. In the tweak tool, I've assigned Hyper to CapsLock. I have also fixed the issue where Super and Hyper result in the same thing, using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423627/how-to-make-hyper-and-super-keys-not-do-the-same-thing). If I look in `xev`, if I press CapsLock it now says `Hyper_L` as expected, and pressing Super results in `Super_L`.

The problem is, if I go to the keyboard shortcut settings and actually assign something, for instance to Hyper+L, it actually says there that the shortcut is set to Hyper+L. But when I exit the settings and press Hyper+L, nothing happens. If I assign the shortcut to Super+L, exit the settings, and press Super+L, the shortcut triggers and does the thing I assigned it to.

How can I make GNOME listen to my Hyper shortcuts?

Comment: It's not my question, so I can't accept anything. But as I mentioned, both answers of that question worked in the sense that xev now can tell the difference between the two keys, so it's one step closer to the goal. But that question didn't address the point of my question here: when I have assigned a hotkey with hyper, GNOME doesn't trigger it when I press it (and it does with super)

Comment: I am intrigued by your question, so I will experiment a bit myself. There is a good answer here about these keys: https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys Apparently it is not straightforward, and indeed just may not work as expected in Gnome.