# How do I display two windows as split screen?

Tags: window-manager

I have two open programs, but I want to view both of them at the same time. Dragging and adjusting them manually takes time, and I might have to do this every day. Is there any shortcut for doing this in Ubuntu?

I'm thinking something like this:

[image: Screenshot showing two windows side-by-side]

Comment: Ctrl + Alt +Numpad left / Ctrl + Alt +Numpad right. must be here somewhere.

Comment: ...And Ctrl + Alt +Numpad up / Ctrl + Alt +Numpad down for upper/lower half.

Comment: Woa, that's a nice screenshot of an ancient Google on an ancient operating system :)

Comment: You used the wrong screenshot. Windows XP (in the screenshot, it has the Green theme applied) doesn't have such feature (natively). It was introduced in Windows Vista.

Comment: Please don't spam edit like that.

Answer (score 93):

To set a window occupying the left half of the screen use this shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + [<kbd>Super</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys) + <kbd>←</kbd>

For the right half:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + [<kbd>Super</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys) + <kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: Super? What key is that?

Comment: Super is the "windows key"

Comment: For those wondering why @IsmaelMiguel used super: not all keyboards are alike. Many are agnostic to the operating system that it uses. Many vendors,however prefix the super key with the dominant operating system that is bundled with a desktop package. Dell keyboards are labeled with Windows. Apple's equivalent label is the command key. In many ways, I wish more keyboards where agnostic to the OS. WASD keyboards do this and many others.

Comment: @KLVTZ Thank you for explaining. This should be addressed in the answer.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)

Comment: Any way to change these shortcuts?

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: @Wizard79 Just tried it out, works perfectly on 14.04.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa tried yesterday and again now, not working on 14.04. It works on my other Ubuntu machine, 17.10.

Comment: @Wizard79 You must file a bug report. This functionality is common to all Unity 7 releases. There is something wrong with your particular set-up.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa solved: this works only with Compiz, I'm using Metacity

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, "Ctrl + Alt + Arrow" worked for me.

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 it is `Super + ←/→`.

Comment: @Tushar These shortcuts are the same on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: For Ub 20.04.1 it's also **Super + ←/→**

Comment: What about making a window 1/4 of the screen (e.g. in upper right corner)?

Comment: @Tushar god bless you!

Answer (score 20):

You can also just drag the window all the way to the left or right edge of the screen, it will show an animation that highlights the new dimension and then just release it.

Comment: OP mentioned that is *not* what he wants to do.

Comment: Oh, read over that bit for some reason.. sorry!

Comment: Happens to me all the time :)

Comment: Although he talks about "Dragging and adjusting them manually takes time".. which implies that he tries to resize it to take the half of the screen manually..

Comment: You might be right...

Comment: OP sounds like he is fiddling with window sizes manually (collapse from maximize, drag each window edge to line up with right of screen, middle of screen, top of screen, bottom of screen...). Gladen's answer sounds a lot more like Windows 7's aero snap, which is basically "drag title bar to edge of screen and it fills half the screen for you", which takes like a second to do.

Comment: While the cursor itself moves close to the edge, while the window is being dragged, you should see a translucent orange field appear.

Comment: Tho it's tedious !!