# Using Mac-OS shortcuts in Intellij IDEA with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, macosx, intellij

I'm very familiar with Mac OS shortcuts and I'd like to use them in Ubuntu also. But the keymap is full of `Meta` button and I couldn't figure out how to do that. Any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You can make to use <kbd>Win</kbd> key as `Meta`

For to do this, go to `System Settings | Keyboard Layout | Options...`  at this point expand `Alt/Win key behavior` and choose **`Meta is mapped to Win keys`** option.

So now when you setup Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap on IntelliJ it should work as you are used to.

For more information about Meta key read this [discussion](https://askubuntu.com/q/19558/181228).

Comment: Any chance you could provide the updated location on where to find these settings in 16.04?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find the option suggested by the other answer as I did, you might need to install the `gnome-tweak-tool` package (`apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`). Then open Tweak Tool and go to Typing > Alt/Win key behaviour and customize it there.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04, you should relace the command (aka. **Windows/ Win**) key with the **meta** key.

1. Run `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
2. Run `gnome-tweaks`
3. Click `Keyboard & Mouse` > `Additional Layout Options` > `Expand Alt/Win key behaviour` > `Select "Meta is mapped to Win" (2nd last in list)`

[image: Screenshot of additional layout options]