# Keyboard Layout: Mac keyboard and Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I managed to configure most of the things I wanted when using a Mac keyboard with Ubuntu.
But there is one last thing : the left alt key.

Specifically, to to tilde (~), I have to press Right Alt + n.
But I would prefer to do it with Left Alt...

I tried to edit the Xmodmap file.

```
keycode 64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
```

But it doesn't work...

Also, I read that it is possible using the Keyboard Layout option. 
([What are the meta, super, and hyper keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys))
But where is it ?!!!
When I open System settings -> Keyboard, I never find the Options. I have Text entry and Shortcuts but that's it :/

Thanks for your help !

Mu

Comment: It is important to notice that I have a FRENCH mac keyboard ;)