# Recommendation for custom keyboard shortcut combinations?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Is there a recommendation with regard to how keyboard shortcut combinations for custom applications should be constructed so that they do not interfere with Ubuntu's default shortcuts or shortcuts of other applications such as web browsers?

Sensible examples I can think of:

- <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd>

What would you recommend to use as a system-wide scheme for custom apps shortcuts?

Comment: I think you only need to ensure that your custom app's shortcuts don't conflict with shortcuts used by the system (and the window manager).

Comment: Thank you! So, basically all shortcuts shown by pressing and holding <kbd>Meta</kbd> key?

Answer (score 1):

After experimentation, I found that the combination less likely to be used by any program is the following:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd>

Comment: Please look at `meta` here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys. In your answer, do you refer to the `Windows` aka `Super` key as `meta`?

Comment: Yes, apologies. I edited my answer.