# What is the "Alternative Characters Key"?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

On Ubuntu 15.10 I see in `Settings / Keyboard / Shortcuts / Typing` The "Compose Key" and the "Alternative Characters key". I know what the former is, but not the latter. Does it duplicate the functionality of the compose key (Ubuntu allows to set it to the same keys as the compose key)? Are there any examples of its use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the meta, super, and hyper keys?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys)

Comment: Alternative Characters Key is another name for AltGr. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey (the article uses AltGr to get a Compose Key)

Comment: I see. My confusion arose from seeing that the "Alternative Characters Key" is "Disabled" on the dialog I mentioned above. However, AltGr works perfectly. All third-level modifier symbols appear, when I press AltGr. That led me to think it is something else. By the way, how come it works if it is disabled?

Comment: The option exists to add an AltGr if your layout doesn't have one. Since you know what AltGr is, and you say it works fine, I'm guessing you're on a layout which does have AltGr. I don't, but I could map, say, Right Alt to AltGr. If you have an AltGr, that option is superfluous.

Comment: Ohh, that's perfectly clear. Indeed, my keyboard has an AltGr key. So, this is just a way to simulate it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

muru's comment answers the question:

> Alternative Characters Key is another name for AltGr. See [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key), [help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) (the article uses AltGr to get a Compose Key) – muru [Mar 29 '16 at 17:33](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751573/what-is-the-alternative-characters-key#comment1120833_751573)