# Mapping Left Control to Hyper using xkb

Tags: xkb

How can I map left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to behave as hyper (left hyper) using xkb?
Look at this in `keycodes/evdev`:

```
// Fake keycodes for virtual keys
<LVL3> =   92;
<MDSW> =   203;
<ALT>  =   204;
<META> =   205;
<SUPR> =   206;
<HYPR> =   37;
```

Why these are fake? I set `<HYPR>` to 37 to do the mapping but now left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keysym (using `xev`) is `keysym 0x0, NoSymbol`. I guess it's related to the comment above these lines. Any ideas?
(I can do it with `xmodmap`, but I want it with `xkb`.)

Comment: Do you really mean `hyper`, not `super`? AFAIK `hyper` has no functionality in Ubuntu. You can read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19565) if you aren't sure which key you want to map.

Comment: I mean `hyper` not `super`, shift, control, alt and super aren't enough for my usecase. I need another modifier to achieve what I need. I'm able to get what I want with `xmodmap` but it's really unstable and I have this feeling that it even consumes cpu (when I disable my xmodmap modifications gnome works much smoother.) so I wanna do it with xkb. I have other modifications in xkb layer and it works stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did so:
Edited `evdev` to:

```
...
<CAPS> = 37;
...
<LCTL> = 66;
...
```

`<LCTL> = 66` was already there as I wanted caps to be left control. I just made left control produce caps with `<CAPS> = 37`
and then edited `symbols/pc` to:

```
...
key <CAPS> {    [ Hyper_L       ]   };
...
```

Now I wonder if I can do these changes in a dotfile in my home directory.