# Setting gnome window-switching to Hyper doesn't work

Tags: gnome, xkb

Applying these gsettings doesn't work:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows ['<Hyper>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward ['<Hyper><Shift>Tab']
```

Same when using Hyper for switch-applications and cycle-windows - that also doesn't work.

When e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> is used, all combinations work.

What does Hyper not work?

Edit : Posted a bug report here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/778

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. I have read that post, but I cannot quite see how that post addresses the question? Many thanks.

Comment: It gives some insight about the Hyper key, and as to why "<Hyper>" may not work.

Comment: Yes, many thanks. Nothing about the document seems to indicate why Hyper would be any different from e.g. Super. Did I miss that?

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion to look at the keyboard with xev led me to identifying the likely issue (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552680/why-does-hypertab-not-work-tested-in-ubuntu-gnome-and-xfce). In particular,

```
xmodmap -pm
```

showed that mod5 was overcrowded, where my modifications had been included with the default map (for the xkb US keyboard layout) of:

```
mod4        Super_L (0x25),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

to give

```
mod4        Super_L (0x25),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        <OTHER_KEYS, inc. Hyper_R> ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

So ISO_Level3_Shift was triggered along Hyper, and thus didn't work.

However, by setting  to Super, and then using different mod numbers, Hyper works as advertised. For details, see writeup here: https://github.com/bjohas/Ubuntu-keyboard-map-like-OS-X/blob/master/Hyper%20key.md