# My keyboard doesn't have Super button. Can I do anything to fix this?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am using a Lenovo PC which doesn't have a <kbd>Super</kbd> button.
Using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Your keyboard does not have a key with the Windows logo on it? What model of Lenovo is this?

Comment: What exactly are you aiming at? Use another button instead of Super?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details. (some of us like old IBM Model M keyboards which pre-date super keys so work-arounds are possible but your release details & desktop are a starting point).

Comment: So the super key and the Windows logo key are the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the meta, super, and hyper keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1445421/1157519

Answer (score 3):

The super key and the Windows logo key are the same.