# What is the Super key?

Tags: notification

I'm trying to see the notification list.

The notification list gives you a way to get back to your notifications when it is convenient for you. It appears when you click on the clock, or press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. The notification list contains all the notifications that you have not acted upon or that permanently reside in it.

What is Super?

Comment: `Super` is the "Start" button on the keyboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the meta, super, and hyper keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)

Comment: the duplicate should be found with a simple search

Comment: Typically, the key with the "Windows logo" on the bottom left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The super key can usually be found on the bottom-left of your keyboard, next to the Alt key, and usually has a Windows logo on it. It is sometimes called the Windows key or system key.

reference:https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-key-super.html.en

Answer (score 34):

Typically it sits between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>. If you're lucky, it looks like this:

[image]

But sadly, it typically looks like a Windows logo. Here are some designs that you may encounter:

[image]

Comment: at least none look like an os/2 logo

Comment: @JonasStumphStevnsvig What do you mean?  Back in the day, OS/2 was the *stuff*.

Comment: Indeed, but the proliferation of general purpose keyboards with OS/2 logo keys has never come to pass... I think most of the keys are either windoze or half-eaten apples...

Comment: I think the history behind this is some popular keyboard in ancient times actually had the buttons labelled META, SUPER and HYPER. But then PC keyboards had different labels, so they decided to make ALT=META and Windows=SUPER.

Answer (score 14):

Super is the Windows key, or the Command key if you use a Mac layout

Comment: Note that depending on the exact keyboard, the logo may not be the Windows logo. I used to have a laptop that came preloaded with Ubuntu and had an Ubuntu logo on the Super key, and the keyboard I’m typing this comment on has a very generic thing that isn’t any logo as far as I can tell.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Yup, thanks for pointing that out. I first thought of the most common keyboard layouts we use.

Answer (score 8):

Super Key is known as "Windows Key" to windows users and "Command Key" to Mac users. Generally it's between control (ctrl) and Alter (alt) button.

Reference - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)