# Desktop larger than the screen

Tags: screen

The cat laid on the keyboard and when I got him off, the desktop was zoomed in so that to see all of it my mouse cursor automatically scrolls. What keys did he hit?

That was on Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) using GNOME.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In GNOME to turn Zoom off and on it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>

Comment: A note: "Super" is often mapped as the "Windows" key.

Comment: Details on what `Super` means can be found in [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/19565)

Answer (score 3):

For future readers:

If you're using XFCE, you can zoom in and out by scrolling while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>. This is the same key you hold to drag windows with LMB or resize them with RMB.

This key can be customized in: Settings➔Window Manager Tweaks➔Accessibility➔Key used to grab and move windows.

Comment: In my xfce it is Alt+mousewheel, but I can't remember if I customized it. It is an UbuntuStudio 20.04 install

Comment: @rapto Hah, apparently I myself did customize it. Fixed.

Comment: I got the same on Ubuntu Studio. Useful now I know, but confusing at first!