# How can I use solaar to map the forward / back buttons on my Logitech MX/2 mouse to next / previous virtual desktop?

Tags: logitech, solaar

I'm having difficulties setting up solaar to remap my mouse forward/back buttons to switch virtual desktops. This is easily configurable using the official logitech software in windows.

I'm finding the rules editor in solaar a bit obtuse, I can't see if it's possible to achieve what I want.

I've diverted the forward button, created a rule which triggers the keys Control_L + Alt_L + Right, but nothing seems to happen.

Does anyone know if I can do this, or what is going wrong with what I've already tried?

Answer (score 1):

I had configured the KWin shortcut as the default "Ctrl+Meta+Right", and then tried to use Solaar to send that keystroke with the MX3 gesture button. Figured it would work fine, but Solaar was actually sending that to the OS as Ctrl+Alt+Right. Found this by adding a custom shortcut and using the configured mouse button/gesture to be the "input" for the custom shortcut. Sure enough, Solaar wouldn't send Meta (aka Win/Command).

I ended up just leaving the default checked, and now both Ctrl+Meta+Right and Ctrl+Alt+Right both change virtual desktops. You could probably disable the default if two keystroke shortcuts doing the same thing annoys you, but at this point it doesn't appear that Solaar can send Meta properly. Remapping is your workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the response! For some reason, it seems that solaar is sending the key combinations but nothing is receiving them. I've mapped CTRL+1 to switch to the first virtual desktop, and mapped my mouse back button to that key combo. For some reason, it won't switch desktop, but if I highlight a web browser, it DOES receive the CTRL+1 combo to switch to the first browser tab.

Comment: Keep in mind that the [Meta key is not the same as the Super key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys). You probably meant to set it to the Super key instead.