# What is the "Win" key used for on Linux?

Tags: windows, keys

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How can I use the Windows (Super) key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19556/how-can-i-use-the-windows-super-key)

I have a Windows PC, but I installed [Ubuntu 12.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29) (Quantal Quetzal) on it. I have the Win key which displays the Start menu on Windows, but on Ubuntu I think it's useless. Can it be used for something interesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a default installation of Ubuntu, you can press shortly on the windows key to make the dash visible, which is a great tool for searching applications and/or files.

But there are many more useful key combinations enabled by default! Just press the windows key for a little while longer and a cheat sheet with the most useful combinations will be shown. The windows key is there called "Super".

Another very useful combination not mentioned there is [Super] + [W], which shows all open windows of the active workspace nicely arranged. You can then bring one of these windows to the front by clicking on it.

Have fun exploring!

Answer (score 1):

> I have the Win key [...] can it be used for something interesting?

Yes, this is called the <kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd> key in Linux. You can use it in custom key shortcuts, and in Unity it should bring up the [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)#Dash).

Below is an example on how to configure a shortcut using the Windows key in KDE. This should be similar in other [desktop environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment).

[image]

Comment: It would help Abood if you put the format in Unity.

Comment: @nerof61 Is he running Unity? The question does not mention this. "Ubuntu" may refer to any DE. Anyway, I think this isn't overly relevant for the question itself. Feel free to improve the answer by including a screenshot of the Unity-way or by referring to a question for configuring key shortcuts in Unity.

Comment: Ubuntu is run in the Unity format. I will put the format of Unity in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the Windows key, Ubuntu takes you to [Dash Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)#Dash). However, you can refer to *[Use the Windows Key for the "Start" Menu in Ubuntu Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27038/use-the-windows-key-for-the-start-menu-in-ubuntu-linux-10.04/)* for customizing the Windows key.